# CodeIgniter MSSQL connection

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, codeigniter, odbc

I'm working on a web project that is to be deployed on a 64bit Windows 2008 Server machine running IIS 7.5 and PHP 5.3.8. The database on the system is Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2. I'm developing the application on the CodeIgniter 2.1.0 framework, and I'm a bit stumped on getting it to connect to the SQL Server.

I've tried using both the MSSQL, ODBC and SQLSRV database drivers, and have encountered three separate errors, for each different driver.

Here is my configuration for ODBC:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'SA';
$db['default']['username'] = 'petre';
$db['default']['password'] = 'start';
$db['default']['database'] = 'petre';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'odbc';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

I have the DNS for SA defined under Data Sources, and I'm sure that the username and password are both valid, and that the server accepts Mixed authentication(Windows + SQL authentication).

I'm auto-loading the DB library and for any page I access I get:

```
Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
Filename: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\system\database\DB_driver.php
Line Number: 124
```

If I try to connect via MSSQL, I just get a blank page, no matter what.

If I try using SQLSRV using the following params:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = '127.0.0.1';
$db['default']['username'] = 'petre';
$db['default']['password'] = 'start';
$db['default']['database'] = 'petre';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'sqlsrv';
```

Even though I'm linking to the sqlsrv DLL file in php.ini, I get the following message:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\system\database\drivers\sqlsrv\sqlsrv_driver.php on line 76
```

I've been reading up on old posts and different views but I've yet to solve the problem.

I'm only looking for a solution for a single DB Driver - anything that gets it to connect is fine. Does anyone have any advice on solving this?

Comment: Can you make the connection using PHP's built-in functions for connecting to MSSQL or ODBC (thus taking CodeIgniter out of the equation)?

Comment: "If I try to connect via MSSQL, I just get a blank page, no matter what" sound like a fatal/parse/similar error, check your php.ini to make sure you log such errors in a file, and post the relevant log lines in your question

Comment: @Crontab As soon as I tried your solution, I found out that the problem was CodeIgniter's built-in ODBC driver, which adds apostrophes around the table names. I had a quick look through odbc_driver.php, changed the way tables are referenced and that solved the issue!

Comment: @PetrePatrasc: Good, I'm glad you could track it down!

Comment: Hi, now I'm facing this issue. But I changed apostrophes even though it is not working. I have tried both odbc and mssql in dbdriver. I'm connecting remote server shared in another hosting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are showing for the SQLSRV driver implies the DLL is never loading. What does your php_info() say?

Also, do you have the SQL Server Native Access Client (SNAC) 10 installed? The SQLSRV driver requires it.

Comment: Thanks, that was the stepping-stone to solving the problem. I found out that the problem was CodeIgniter's built-in ODBC driver, which adds apostrophes around the table names.

Answer (score 3):

For **x86 win** download `http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098` for using with:

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'sqlsrv';
use the php_sqlsrv_XX_ts_vcX.dll in php.ini extension
```

if your webserver and your database server are not on same server with your app, install this:

```
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=188400&clcid=0x409
```

and for **linux** as webserver:

$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mssql';

```
download & install = php5-sybase + freetds
<br/>edit /usr/local/etc/freetds.conf
<br/>create pdo_dblib.so & php_mssql.so (if not allready exist on your extension dir), and apply to php.ini

sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

and just dont forget to allow connection to your DB (default port for mssql is 1433)