# How do I connect to a SQL Server database in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, codeigniter, configuration, connection

How do I connect to a SQL Server database in CodeIgniter?

I'm currently starting an application in CodeIgniter and I would like to use SQL Server.

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = '#.#.#.27';
$db['default']['username'] = '@@@@@@';
$db['default']['password'] = '@@@@@@@@@';
$db['default']['database'] = '$$$$$$$$$$$$$';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mssql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

After auto-loading the database, it shows just a blank white page with no errors. Can you please tell me what other changes I have to make to work with the SQL Server database?

```
#autoload.php#
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to enable PHP's error reporting.

Comment: @shanethehat , tried with error_reporting () values in the main index.php file. not succeed.

Answer (score 3):

use use $db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'sqlsrv';

and install Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server on windows

[CodeIgniter MSSQL connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669337/codeigniter-mssql-connection/13433923)

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't get it to work with the *supported* driver of `mssql` so I used `sqlsrv`

I normally connect with *ip,port* as the `hostname`, so I changed that.

`pconnect` was also giving me issues. I set it to `FALSE` and it started working.

Here is the configuration I got to work:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = '127.0.0.1,1433';
$db['default']['username'] = 'username1';
$db['default']['password'] = 'secretpassword';
$db['default']['database'] = 'databasename';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'sqlsrv';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this? I've seen it work on some servers. Is this a Windows server?

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = "odbc";
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = "";
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
```

[further reading](http://codefury.net/2011/01/codeigniter-php-iis-mysql-mssql/)

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Your Configuration code is fine. Further reading [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html)

IF you believe the  errors are not showing up, then go to the `index.php` and on the top place the following snippet  to show the errors.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Other, then this check if the MSSQL service is running and is accessible. May be create a simple `.php` and try a connection with **plain codes**.

A non CI file Something like,

```
<?php
$server = 'YOURPC\SQLEXPRESS';
$link = mssql_connect($server, 'user', 'pass');

if (!$link) {
    die('Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

it is the same process as mysql.
use the same configuration given below:

> $active_group = 'default';
>   $active_record = TRUE;
>
> $db['default']['hostname'] = 'xxx.xx.xx.xx\SQLEXPRESS';
>
> $db['default']['username'] = 'sa';
>
> $db['default']['password'] =
>
> 'xxxxxxx'; $db['default']['database'] = 'xxxxx';
>
> $db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mssql';
>
> $db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
>
> $db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
>
> $db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
>
> $db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
>
> $db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
>
> $db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
>
> $db['default']['dbcollat'] => 'utf8_general_ci';
>
> $db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
>
> $db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
>
> $db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;

In your Model use same as

> function selectagent($table,$agent)
>       {
>
> $field = $this->db->get_where($table, array('var1'
>   =>$agent,'day(date)'=>date('d')));
>
> ```
>   $fields=$field->result();
>
>   return $fields;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I just got this problem solved. And I was connecting to MSSQL hosted with microsoft Azure

Steps I followed after several research work on internet are as follows :

database.cfg :

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'XXXXXXX.database.windows.net';
$db['default']['username'] = 'username';
$db['default']['password'] = 'password';
$db['default']['database'] = 'databasename';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'sqlsrv';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Mainly dbdriver,pcconnect and the hostname you should configure properly. Rest are common. Get hostname from your azure database details.

And I also modified couple of system files as I heard there were issues with DB driver.

system/database/drivers/sqlsrv/sqlsrv_driver.php

```
function db_pconnect()
    {
        //$this->db_connect(TRUE);
        return $this->db_connect(TRUE);
    }
```

and

```
function affected_rows()
{
    //return @sqlrv_rows_affected($this->conn_id);
    return @sqlsrv_num_rows($this->result_id);
}
```

I was able to connect to database and create database application.

Hope it will help someone in need :)

Answer (score 0):

Follow these simple steps:

1. Install the instance with "mixed mode"-enabled. If your unsure watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D0O_MCez5R0&t=602s) - video starts at the right sequence. Maybe it's a good idea to watch it completely.
2. change the db-config in '*...ci/application/config/database.php*'

   ```
   $active_group = 'default';
   $query_builder = TRUE;

   $db['default'] = array(
       'dsn' => '',
       'hostname' => 'localhost',
       'username' => 'sa', // <- use 'sa'
       'password' => 'THE_PASSWORD_YOU_SET_ON_INSTALL', // "mixed-mode"
       'database' => 'ci',
       'dbdriver' => 'sqlsrv',
   //  'dbdriver' => 'mysqli', // <- my old "non-server" config (approx. 70% slower)
       'dbprefix' => '',
       'pconnect' => FALSE,
       'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
       'cache_on' => FALSE,
       'cachedir' => '',
       'char_set' => 'utf8',
       'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
       'swap_pre' => '',
       'encrypt' => FALSE,
       'compress' => FALSE,
       'stricton' => FALSE,
       'failover' => array(),
       'save_queries' => TRUE
   );
   ```

[image]