# 'Invalid DB driver' error when connecting CodeIgniter framework to Sql Server

Tags: database, codeigniter, driver, sqlsrv

This is the error:

> An Error Was Encountered. 
>   Invalid DB driver

I am using CodeIgniter 3.1.9 framework for a website and I am on the process of connecting the database I imported on HeidiSQL to the framework.

To connect to the database, I decided to install sql server drivers for the specific php version I have (PHP 7.2.9). By the way, I have Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client installed and my operative system is a Windows 7 Professional 64 bits.

I created a folder inside CodeIgniter named 'sqlsrv' and installed the drivers inside.

I configured php.ini file like this, adding the extensions needed:

```
extension=sqlsrv
extension=php_sqlsrv.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_72_ts_x64.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_72_ts_x86.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_ts_x64.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_ts_x86.dll
extension=php_pdo.dll
```

And here is the database.php configuration file (server/hostname, port, username, database/dbname and password values are not real for safety):

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => 'Driver={SQL Server 2012 Native Client};server=192.168.7.88;port=1422;dbname=database_name;username=user_name;password=pass',
    'hostname' => '192.168.7.88', 
    'username' => 'user_name', 
    'password' => 'pass', 
    'database' => 'database_name', 
    'dbdriver' => 'sqlsrv', 
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE, 
    'db_debug' => TRUE ,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'autoinit' => TRUE, 
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE

);
```

I tried changing the content inside 'dsn' value and leaving it empty, enabling more sql server drivers and infinite other ways like using odb (not useful because query builder is not allowed) alternatively and it's still not working.

Comment: try the pdo variant - something like `'dsn'   => 'sqlsrv:server=192.168.7.88,1422;Database=database_name'` and your driver should be `'dbdriver' => 'pdo'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I connect to a SQL Server database in CodeIgniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9973022/how-do-i-connect-to-a-sql-server-database-in-codeigniter)