# How to connect Codeigniter 2.1.x with sqlsrv

Tags: sql-server, codeigniter, wamp, codeigniter-2, sqlsrv

I have the following conf database

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'xx.xx.xx.xx,1433';
$db['default']['username'] = 'user';
$db['default']['password'] = 'pass';
$db['default']['database'] = 'dbname';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'sqlsrv';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Codeigniter get me the Unable to connect to database using the parameters entered...what's wrong? i try the following connection for $db['default']['hostname']

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'xx.xx.xx.xx,1433';
$db['default']['hostname'] = '(xx.xx.xx.xx),1433';
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'xx.xx.xx.xx:1433';
```

and it don't work
Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: is the  sql server port

Comment: ocrama check my answer

Answer (score 2):

Set

```
$db['default']['pconnect'] = false;
```

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

**You added hostname and port number together codeigniter has a setting to define port number**

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'xx.xx.xx.xx';
$db['default']['username'] = 'user';
$db['default']['password'] = 'pass';
$db['default']['database'] = 'dbname';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'sqlsrv';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['port'] = 1433;
```

For more details go to http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/configuration.html

Comment: I have inserted the following line
    $db['default']['port'] = 1433;

Now my database conf is exactly as you post me.
But still don't work
the error is the same:


"A Database Error Occurred
  Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
 Filename: C:\wamp\www\myssite\system\database\DB_driver.php
  Line Number: 124"

Comment: @ocrama check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669337/codeigniter-mssql-connection/13433923 do you have sql server extension for php ? Also, do you have the SQL Server Native Access Client (SNAC) 10 installed ?

Comment: @ocrama also check this one http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/208171/#1017407

Comment: i'm using WAMP server and i have all the extension for sqlsrv: it appear in my phpinfo. i also have SQL Server Native Access Client (SNAC) 10 because in the same machine i have installed sql server management studio. The problem is maybe WAMP?

Comment: Alternatively, in Ubuntu is possibile to make work Codeigniter with sqlsrv?