# CI connect to SQL SERVER

Tags: php, sql-server, database, codeigniter, sqlsrv

i want to connect to sql server my php version is 5.4 and i have MS SQL Server 2008 R2 and i use PHP Codeigniger 2.1.4
i use sqlsrv30.exe
i use XAMPP 1.8.2

i change database.php config

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = '192.168.5.208';
$db['default']['username'] = 'xxx';
$db['default']['password'] = 'xxx';
$db['default']['database'] = 'xxx';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'sqlsrv';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

i download sqlsrv30.exe. install it in php/ext

i add the following on the php.ini file:

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
```

i install Native Client 10

i change sqlsrv_driver.php in folder database-driver-sqlsrv to

```
function db_pconnect() {
        //return $this->db_connect(TRUE);
        return $this->db_connect(TRUE);
    }
```

i also try add

```
db['default']['port'] = 1433;
```

but its still not working. I always encountered the ff. error:

```
A Database Error Occurred
Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\HRM\system\database\DB_driver.php
Line Number: 124
```

Please help...

Comment: Set `dbdriver` as `mssql`. The list of available dbdrivers in CI : `mysql, mysqli, postgre, odbc, mssql, sqlite, oci8`

Comment: most say mssql not avaible for php 5.3 and latter so i use sqlsrv, i install xampp 1.8.2 and not found mssql.dll include..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same trouble you've had about a year ago. Have a look at the replies here, there are some great suggestions from people in there: [CodeIgniter MSSQL connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669337/codeigniter-mssql-connection)

@StefenWiranata Sorry, just noticed part 2 of your comment - I can't remember where I'd made the change, but I can try and look tonight if you can't get it solved. I know for sure that CI was adding apostrophes around the table names somewhere in system/database/drivers/odbc/, most likely in the odbc_driver.php file.

Comment: sorry for troubling you, and my bad english , i dont understand your solution in there , i spend my whole time because this problem, what you use ? sqlsrv or odbc ? " I found out that the problem was CodeIgniter's built-in ODBC driver, which adds apostrophes around the table names. I had a quick look through odbc_driver.php, changed the way tables are referenced", what you change ? please help..

Comment: @StefenWiranata I went for ODBC in that example, since I couldn't get "sqlsrv" to work under PHP 5.3.

Comment: @StefenWiranata Hey man, just updated my answer to reflect part 2 of your comment.

Comment: thank you for your help , finally i figured it out, try to show sqlsrv error by add die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true)); on DB_driver and read the error log

Answer (score 2):

My mysql had the same problem in the same line and I search a lot for it. It may be your 'port' or 'autoinit'. But mine finally resovled by addressed some problem in server. So check your server is another way.

Comment: i check sql server port is 1433 , and change false autoinit , but it's just prevent init db when first load , that not solve the problem , what do you mean with addressed some problem in server ? please help..

Comment: I'm so sorry, that problem was solved by another department. So I don't  know what that problem is.

Answer (score 2):

Finally figure it out , add die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true)); on DB_driver and read the error log and solve your problem , for me because I just install Native Client 10 and the sqlsrv3.0 require Native Client 11.

Comment: When you can finally get some error output the solution is obvious. Thank you very much for this tip!