# Codeigniter: How to setup connection to a SQL server (2008)

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008, codeigniter, sqlsrv

I've spent many days on this task, and I can't see the end until now. In the past day I managed to install sqlsrv driver on my PHP environment successfully but now when I try to connect I get this message:

> Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

My settings in `application/config/database.php` are so defined:

```
$db['dbname']['hostname'] = "ENJ01\SQLEXPRESS";
$db['dbname']['username'] = "user";
$db['dbname']['password'] = "password";
$db['dbname']['database'] = "dbname";
$db['dbname']['dbdriver'] = "sqlsrv";
$db['dbname']['dbprefix'] = "";
$db['dbname']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['dbname']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['dbname']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['dbname']['cachedir'] = "";
$db['dbname']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$db['dbname']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
$db['dbname']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['dbname']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['dbname']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

something wrong?

Here my environment configuration:

- wampserver 2.4 x86
- PHP 5.4.16
- sqlsrv driver -> php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
- Codeigniter 2.1.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the same trouble you've had about a year ago. Have a look at the replies here, there are some great suggestions from people in there: [CodeIgniter MSSQL connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669337/codeigniter-mssql-connection)

Also, a thread was posted a few days ago here: [CI connect to SQL SERVER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19396611/ci-connect-to-sql-server/19398832#19398832) - check out my answer over there as well, since it's solved the problem for that particular developer.

Comment: I've added "die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));" on DB_driver as suggested in the post you linked, and after some corrections following the error messages, now I got the connection!!!

Comment: @Splact Great to hear mate, make sure you update your question with the answer that was appropriate for you, so that people can reference it easier.

Answer (score 0):

I would've wrote a comment, but I haven't the required reputation yet. Anyways...

I noticed your hostname 'ENJ01\SQLEXPRESS', have you tried using 'localhost' instead?

Also, try setting the port to 1433, with $db['dbname']['port'] = 1433;

Comment: I've tried, but nothing changed. Somewhere here on stackoverflow I read that I've to use "(local), 1433" as hostname, but nothing also there...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem solved by setting

$ db ['default'] ['pconnect'] = FALSE;

Answer (score -1):

Make
1. `$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;`.
Then go to `system/database/drivers/sqlsrv/sqlsrv_driver.php`

```
function db_pconnect()
    {
        //$this->db_connect(TRUE);
        return $this->db_connect(TRUE);
    }
```

and

```
function affected_rows()
{
    //return @sqlrv_rows_affected($this->conn_id);
    return @sqlsrv_num_rows($this->result_id);
}
```

Comment: db_pconnect() method not available in sqlsrv_driver.php