# mssql_connect(): Unable to connect to server: (192.168.0.139)\PKSRV\SQLSERVER2008 codeigniter error

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am using codeigniter 3 and sql server 2008. i want remote connection with sql server database. But codeigniter is giving error or provided server and error is as my question title. 
can any one help regarding to this. My database setting is as follow

```
$db['default'] = array(
'dsn'   => '',
'hostname' => '(192.168.0.139)\PKSRV\SQLSERVER2008',
'username' => 'xxxxx',
'password' => 'xxxxx',
'database' => 'xxxxx',
'dbdriver' => 'mssql',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Codeigniter: How to setup connection to a SQL server (2008)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19431447/codeigniter-how-to-setup-connection-to-a-sql-server-2008)

Comment: Check this answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19431447/codeigniter-how-to-setup-connection-to-a-sql-server-2008

Comment: thanks Zachu for providing useful link.