# In codeigniter how to setup connection to a SQL server

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008, codeigniter-3

I have spent many days on this task, and I can not see the end until now.

settings in application/config/database.php

I have two servers, in first server i have installed PHP and Xammp and in 2nd server have SQL Server and authentication mode is Windows

```
$db['attn'] = array(
'dsn'   => '10.166.32.21',
'hostname' => 'APP01/MSSQLSERVER2012',
'username' => 'DOMAIN/Administrator',
'password' => '',
'database' => 'xample',
'dbdriver' => 'sqlsrv',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE);
```

I have latest version of PHP and CodeIgniter

anything wrong is my configuration

```
public function connect_sql()
{
    try
    {
        $live = $this->load->database('attn',TRUE);
    }
    catch (Exception $e) 
    {
        echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: i already tried and it is not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Codeigniter: How to setup connection to a SQL server (2008)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19431447/codeigniter-how-to-setup-connection-to-a-sql-server-2008)

Comment: @SamSwift웃 read question first

Comment: Have you installed the necessary drivers to be able to use mssql? PHP to MSSQL is tricky as you not only need to update your database config but you also have to install the necessary drivers.

Comment: @hungrykoala yes everything is installed

Comment: What have you installed then? Did you also update php.ini to include the drivers?

Comment: Check `php_info()` to see if you have the necessary drivers for MSSQL

Comment: @hungrykoala yes i configured already, in same server its works normally

Comment: What do you mean by it works normally in the same server?

Comment: @hungrykoala did you read my Question ??

Answer (score 0):

```
'dsn'   => '',
'hostname' => '10.166.32.21',
'username' => 'your db user name',
'password' => 'your db password',
```