# How to connect Codeigniter with MSSQL (SQL Server)?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, codeigniter, database-connection

My server use Windows Server with MSSQL 2012. While I am use OS X (El Capitan) with XAMPP (Apache) for Mac and develop website using Codeigniter 2.2.0.

Here is my configuration :

```
$active_group = 'my_mssql';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['my_mssql']['hostname'] = 'xx.xx.xx.x';
$db['my_mssql']['username'] = 'wow_queue';
$db['my_mssql']['password'] = 'wow12345';
$db['my_mssql']['database'] = 'queue_sys';
$db['my_mssql']['dbdriver'] = 'mssql';
$db['my_mssql']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['my_mssql']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['my_mssql']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['my_mssql']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['my_mssql']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['my_mssql']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['my_mssql']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['my_mssql']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['my_mssql']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['my_mssql']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

but the results is :

[image: 1]

Are my settings be wrong?

I just want to be able to connect to that server. Does anyone have any advice on solving this?

Comment: Possible answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669337/codeigniter-mssql-connection

Answer (score 4):

it will be helpful for someone

Detail steps for How to connect SQL Server with PHP in WampServer

step 1)

download the appropriate driver based on your php version, check using php_info() function, for me 5.6, so the appropriate driver is SQLSRV30, found in the following link
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098

step 2) extract the drives in C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.19\ext
focus on the following .dll file they should be there, otherwise we can't connect with SQL, these are

php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll and php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll

step 3) enable the drives in php.ini 
as follow, which is found in C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.18\bin as follow

extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll 
extension=php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll

step 4) go to  DB_driver.php line 96
found in
C:\wamp\www\public\system\database\DB_driver.php
please replace the  mysqli  by sqlsrv

```
public $dbdriver = ' mysqli  '; 
 public $dbdriver = 'sqlsrv';
```

step 5) last and most important part, go to CI database config
in database.php file which's found in C:\wamp\www\public\application\config\database.php
adjust the params accordingly...

$db['default'] = array(

```
'dsn' => '',
'hostname' => 'ip address for sql server,port', // it should be SQL TCP enabled and firewall permitted for SQL port, whether default or custom.
'username' => 'your user name here',
'password' => 'your pwd here',
'database' => 'your db here',
'dbdriver' => 'sqlsrv',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => TRUE,
'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'autoinit' => TRUE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
```

);

happy coding...

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try odbc driver (built-in db driver in PHP). Mssql driver doesn't come convenient in PHP.

I got this working with CI 2.2.0 connected to MSSQL 2014 database (all Windows platform). I've also tried this using MSSQL 2012 before.

```
$active_group = 'my_mssql';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['my_mssql']['hostname'] = 'Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=Host\Instance;Database=queue_sys;';
$db['my_mssql']['username'] = 'wow_queue';
$db['my_mssql']['password'] = 'wow12345';
$db['my_mssql']['database'] = '';
$db['my_mssql']['dbdriver'] = 'odbc';
$db['my_mssql']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['my_mssql']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['my_mssql']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['my_mssql']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['my_mssql']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['my_mssql']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['my_mssql']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['my_mssql']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['my_mssql']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['my_mssql']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Note:

`SQL Server Native Client 11.0` or `SQL Server Native Client 10.0`, just play with both settings.

`Server=xx.xx.xx.x` usually is in the format `Server=Host\Instance`
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error is showing that SQLSRV driver implies the DLL is not loading ever. 
check your php_info() 
The SQLSRV driver requires for it.
check this for step by step solution

https://futbolsalas15.wordpress.com/2014/02/23/7-steps-to-make-sql-server-and-codeigniter-works/

Comment: What if I use MSSQL driver in Codeigniter? And I use OS X.. not Windows.