# database connection error code igniter sqlsrv

Tags: sql-server, database, codeigniter

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'IP',
    'username' => 'xxxxxxx',
    'password' => 'xxxxxxx',
    'database' => 'xxxxxxx',
    'dbdriver' => 'sqlsrv',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => FALSE
);
```

> http://127.0.0.1:8008/project/

```
Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/project/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 436
```

In my project I have the above database config and url to access the project.
I am getting the error in connection of database when access the project but accessing the database using Microsoft SQL Management Studio using the same credential I dont have problem.

What is the correct setting to connect?

Comment: have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37694308/how-to-connect-codeigniter-with-mssql-sql-server

Comment: @user969068 it uses `odbc` driver im using `sqlsrv` as i mention in OP

Comment: have you installed SQLSRV extension for php?

Comment: @user969068 yes all settings are OK. I checked it in `phpinfo.php` and I have sqlsrv

Comment: are you able to connect without Codeigniter in PHP ? you can create a test.php with connection function, example can be found here http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php