# Unable to connect using PHP 7.2.4 with SQL Server 2008

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, database-connection, codeigniter-3, windows-server-2008-r2

I have newly installed `PHP 7.2.4 and Apache 2.4` on `windows server 2008 r2`. Everything done; i have set the paths, but problem is that when i configuring my `PHP` file for the connection, it gives me an error unable to connect with database.  I am using `codeIgniter 3.1.8`.

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn' => '', 
    'hostname' => 'localhost', 
    'username' => 'root', 
    'password' => '', 
    'database' => 'database_name', 
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli', 
    'dbprefix' => '', 
    'pconnect' => TRUE, 
    'db_debug' => TRUE, 
    'cache_on' => FALSE 
)
```

Comment: show ur database configuration file

Comment: `$db['default'] = array(
        'dsn'   => '',
        'hostname' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => 'database_name',
        'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
        'dbprefix' => '',
        'pconnect' => TRUE,
        'db_debug' => TRUE,
        'cache_on' => FALSE
)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter MSSQL connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669337/codeigniter-mssql-connection)

Comment: pls read : http://mario-loza.blogspot.in/2013/06/how-to-connect-codeigniter-to-ms-sql.html

Comment: Why is your dbdriver `'mysqli'`?

Answer (score 0):

define('ENVIRONMENT','development'); This is a Codeigniter 3, database.php (non SSPI) snippet example for MSSQL 2008R2:

```
 define('ENVIRONMENT','development');                            
 $db['test1'] = array( 'dsn'    => '',
    'hostname' => 'MY_MSSQL_DB_FQDN\i1,10001',
    'username' => 'somemssqluser',
    'password' => 'somemssqlpassword',
    'database' => 'somedbname',
    'dbdriver' => 'sqlsrv',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```