# Can't get Code Igniter to connect to local SQL Server Express instance

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, php-5.3

I have been struggling for the last three hours with the following issue and so far I can't get this to work properly.

I have an SQL Express instance running in my PC, I have checked already the port `1433` is listening by running `netstat -an`:

[image]

I am able to connect through `telnet` by using the following command:

```
telnet SQLEXPRESS 1433
```

This is how my `database.php` file looks like:

```
$active_group = 'mssql_common';

$db['mssql_common']['hostname'] = 'SQLEXPRESS';
$db['mssql_common']['username'] = 'ssEPA_User';
$db['mssql_common']['password'] = '**********';
$db['mssql_common']['database'] = 'ssEPA_DEV';
$db['mssql_common']['dbdriver'] = 'mssql';
$db['mssql_common']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['mssql_common']['pconnect'] = false;
$db['mssql_common']['db_debug'] = true;
$db['mssql_common']['cache_on'] = false;
$db['mssql_common']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['mssql_common']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['mssql_common']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['mssql_common']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['mssql_common']['autoinit'] = true;
$db['mssql_common']['stricton'] = false;
$db['mssql_common']['port']     = 1433;
```

But for some reason, unknown to me, I keep getting the following error:

> Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
>   Filename: core/Loader.php
>   Line Number: 346

For the `hostname` setting I have tried all this combinations (one at a time):

```
$db['mssql_common']['hostname'] = 'SQLEXPRESS'; // instance name
$db['mssql_common']['hostname'] = 'ARX1607\SQLEXPRESS'; // pc_name\instance name
$db['mssql_common']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['mssql_common']['hostname'] = '127.0.0.1';
$db['mssql_common']['hostname'] = '192.168.56.1'; // DHCP address
```

None of the above worked. This is driving me crazy!!!

> **Note:** I am using Code Igniter 2.3.1 (legacy application and I can't
>   upgrade) and PHP 5.3.3 (do not ask me why :p lol) The app is running
>   inside a VirtualBox box using Vagrant so PHP, Apache are on the server
>   side (guest), SQLServer is on Windows side (host).

Does any have any ideas?

I have checked a few posts here like:

- [How to connect code igniter 3.1.8 with sql server 2000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50071924/how-to-connect-code-igniter-3-1-8-with-sql-server-2000)
- [CodeIgniter MSSQL connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669337/codeigniter-mssql-connection/13433923)
- [Codeigniter: How to setup connection to a SQL server (2008)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19431447/codeigniter-how-to-setup-connection-to-a-sql-server-2008)
- [CodeIgniter MSSQL connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669337/codeigniter-mssql-connection)

And tried almost everything but use `sqlsrv` driver. Again, any ideas?

The `mssql` driver is installed and enabled see below:

[image]

Comment: What does `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` say about `mssql`> Thanks.

Comment: @Zhorov what do you mean? if the library is installed and enabled? if so then yes both things ... I can add that part to the OP if needed lmk.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you try to connect to MS SQL using `mssql` driver. That means, that you must see `mssql` section in PHP information.

Comment: @Zhorov yes, I have added that information to the OP!

Comment: I understand.You try to connect to MS SQL server with FreeTDS in Windows environment. I'm not familiar with FreeTDS, all my experience is with `mssql` (php_mssql.dll) and `sqlsrv` (php_sqlsrv.dll) drivers. You may try to install PHP Driver for SQL Server and try with `$db['mssql_common']['dbdriver'] = 'sqlsrv';`. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have `freetds.conf` file? Thanks.

Comment: @Zhorov I do not have such FreeTDS installed not sure what are you assuming I have on your previous comment :)